# Applet need Java Update

Tags: java, applet, sun

I've a problem with Java applets.

I developed two Java applets for my application, the applets are signed with a certificate, include the MANIFEST file with permission and they run correctly.
There is a problem when Oracle releases a new Java update and the applets don't work, it seem that IE look at the latest version of Java and I need to update it every time.

What can cause this problem?

Comment: which version of java were u using before and now it updated to which version ?

Comment: *"i've a problem with Java applets. .. What can cause this problem?"*  'Applets' can.  They are a maintenance nightmare when you factor in how browsers react to them.

Comment: *"There is a problem when "Sun" release a new Java update"*  They won't.  Oracle now owns Java.  ;)

Comment: for George: for example I have updated the java 8.40 to java 8.45 and it's worked fine until the next Oracle release.

Comment: Is there an alternative to applet? I have to upload files without the button "Browse" from my web application, with the applets this works perfectly but this problem with updates it's orrible...

Answer (score 1):

Applets are all but deprecated.  [Your best bet is to migrate away from them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29710181/113632), because more and more browsers are removing support from them.

If you need to enable users to upload files to your server, there are [numerous resources and tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=html%205%20file%20upload) out there.